# Mean value theorem under an expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Consider the expected value of $f$ under the probability density function $\pi(x)$ defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \pi(x) f(x) dx = \mu.
$$

Is there some type of "mean value theorem under expectations" that would allow us to write $\mu = Mf(x^*)$ where $M\in\mathbb{R}$ under some restrictions to $\pi$ and $f$ without requiring that the domain be bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is always true with $M = 1$ and $f$ is continuous. Indeed, if for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x) - \mu$ is always positive then,

\begin{align}
0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \pi (x) \left(f(x)-\mu\right) \mathrm d x 
\end{align}

this implies that $\pi(x) \left(f(x) - \mu \right) = 0$ for all $x$ so $\pi(x) = 0$ for all $x$. This is not possible. Same thing apply when $f(x) - \mu$ is always negative. This proves that $f(x) - \mu$ is zero for some $x$.